# Trying to install Node.js 12 on a Raspberry Pi, somehow ending up with version 10 instead

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, raspberry-pi, debian

I'm trying create a bash installation script to install Node.js version 12 on a Raspberry Pi using:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

When the installation is done, however, I check the version with `node --version`, and I've got v10.24.0 instead.

What would cause this, and how do I stop it from happening?

I'm also finding that `npm` isn't installed unless I instead do:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs npm
```

...and make the installation of `npm` explicit. This sort of works, but then I get warnings every time I use `npm` that `npm` isn't really meant to be used with Node 10.

Am I perhaps missing some prerequisite for version 12, and being automatically downgraded to version 10?

I'm trying to to get this to work with a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with only 1GB RAM. Could that be the issue? My intention was to deliberately install 12 instead of 14 in this installation script if I detect less than 2GB RAM, because I think 14 might require more than 1GB to run reliably. Maybe 1GB is too small for 12 too?

If I try to install again, I get:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (10.24.0~dfsg-1~deb10u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Note: For most of my testing, I'm not using a real Raspberry Pi, but a VM with Debian Linux 10.8 and a Raspberry Pi desktop. The problems are the same on the real hardware, however. The VM just makes testing a LOT faster.

Comment: Is it possible that you have 2 versions of Node.js? Why do you `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
`?

Comment: I'll have to double-check this to be sure, but `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` without running the curl-acquired script first fails, because nodejs isn't a package that's normally available.

Comment: What OS do you use on your Raspberry Pi? I've never run this script and I've always installed Node.js with `apt`. Where did you find this script? Have you updated the repositories with `sudo apt update`?

Comment: It's version 10.

Comment: _"It's version 10."_ is this an answer to one of my questions?

Comment: Yes, I did `sudo apt update`, and it's a fresh install of the latest Raspbian anyway.

Comment: Here's where the script comes from: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Comment: I searched `apt` from my Raspberry Pi and I found `nodejs/stable 10.21.0`. It looks like the script doesn't work for you because `nodejs/stable 10.21.0` is the default withouth script.

Comment: That must be new then. Last time I'd tried this `apt` found nothing on it's own. So I need a way to force installation of 12 over what `apt` locates.

Comment: Did you get this error message `print_status "You appear to be running on ARMv6 hardware. Unfortunately this is not currently supported by the NodeSource Linux distributions. Please use the 'linux-armv6l' binary tarballs available directly from nodejs.org for Node.js 4 and later."`

Comment: If I did get that message, it's lost since the last time I re-imaged the SD card. The VM I'm testing with is Intel, not ARM.

Comment: We need much more information. What OS do you use in the VM? Did you get an error message running the script?

Comment: As I said above, the VM is Debian 10.8. No errors running the script. Now that I know there's an officially-supported `apt` source for Node, I think that's half the battle to understanding this problem. That source apparently has priority over the source set up by the curl-acquired script.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the installed version:

```
sudo apt purge nodejs
```

Download the tarball [from here](https://nodejs.org/dist/), extact it then copy it to  `/usr/local/` (use `uname -a` the get the exact `ARMv*` version):

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.9.1/node-v12.9.1-linux-armv7l.tar.xz
unxz node-v12.9.1-linux-armv7l.tar.xz
tar xvf node-v12.9.1-linux-armv7l.tar
cd node-v12.9.1-linux-armv7l/
sudo cp -R * /usr/local/
```

Comment: Strange result: `which node` gives me `/usr/local/bin/node`, and the binary is definitely there, but `node --version` gives me `-bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory`. I'm beginning to think that, once Raspbian got it's own special version of node, which is version 10, other node distributions just don't work anymore.

Comment: @kshetline and `node -v`?